# Strange background image when opening DMG in Mountain Lion

Tags: finder, osx-mountain-lion, dmg-image

Whenever I open a DMG file to install an application the window opens with a background image from another program I recently installed (Aptana Studio). Below is a screenshot in which I have opened GoogleAppEngineLauncher. But as you can see from the screenshot I can hardly see the icons because of the Aptana background image:

[image]

How do I reset the background image?